# Symfony roles doesn't save in database as array

Tags: php, database, authentication, symfony, roles

The roles of my user entity aren't save well in database.

I have a basic question but I didn't find the solution so I'm asking it myself here.
When I create an user he he's register with the role ROLE_USER. But in my database he's save as a:0:{}
Do you have an idea of what I can do to store them as [] by default.

Comment: That is how arrays are saved to the database. Are you getting any errors? Can you provide some more context such as your user entity and and user creation class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is my user entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use DateTime;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: '`user`', options:["collate"=>"utf8mb4_unicode_ci", "charset"=>"utf8mb4"])]
#[UniqueEntity(fields: ['mail'], message: 'There is already an account with this mail.')]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::ARRAY, nullable: true)]
    private array $roles = [];

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $username = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $password = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $group_role = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $mail = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $firstname = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $lastname = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE, options: ['default' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'])]
    private ?\DateTime $create_datetime = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $notif_rule = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'his_user', targetEntity: Logs::class, orphanRemoval: true)]
    private Collection $logs;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'his_user', targetEntity: Session::class)]
    private Collection $sessions;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'his_user', targetEntity: Access::class, orphanRemoval: true)]
    private Collection $accesses;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->logs = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->sessions = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->accesses = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->create_datetime = new \DateTime( );
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

     /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGroupRole(): ?string
    {
        return $this->group_role;
    }

    public function setGroupRole(string $group_role): self
    {
        $this->group_role = $group_role;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->mail;
    }

    public function setMail(string $mail): self
    {
        $this->mail = $mail;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFirstname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function setFirstname(string $firstname): self
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    public function setLastname(string $lastname): self
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreateDatetime(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->create_datetime;
    }

    public function setCreateDatetime(\DateTimeInterface $create_datetime): self
    {
        $this->create_datetime = $create_datetime;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNotifRule(): ?string
    {
        return $this->notif_rule;
    }

    public function setNotifRule(string $notif_rule): self
    {
        $this->notif_rule = $notif_rule;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Logs>
     */
    public function getLogs(): Collection
    {
        return $this->logs;
    }

    public function addLog(Logs $log): self
    {
        if (!$this->logs->contains($log)) {
            $this->logs->add($log);
            $log->setHisUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeLog(Logs $log): self
    {
        if ($this->logs->removeElement($log)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($log->getHisUser() === $this) {
                $log->setHisUser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Session>
     */
    public function getSessions(): Collection
    {
        return $this->sessions;
    }

    public function addSession(Session $session): self
    {
        if (!$this->sessions->contains($session)) {
            $this->sessions->add($session);
            $session->setHisUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeSession(Session $session): self
    {
        if ($this->sessions->removeElement($session)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($session->getHisUser() === $this) {
                $session->setHisUser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Access>
     */
    public function getAccesses(): Collection
    {
        return $this->accesses;
    }

    public function addAccess(Access $access): self
    {
        if (!$this->accesses->contains($access)) {
            $this->accesses->add($access);
            $access->setHisUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAccess(Access $access): self
    {
        if ($this->accesses->removeElement($access)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($access->getHisUser() === $this) {
                $access->setHisUser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }  

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user
     * 
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->mail;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }
}
```

And here is my route:

```
#[Route('/register', name: 'app_register')]
public function register(Request $request, UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordHasher, UserAuthenticatorInterface $userAuthenticator, UserAuthenticator $authenticator, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
{
$user = new User();
$form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    // encode the plain password
    $user->setPassword(
        $userPasswordHasher->hashPassword(
            $user,
            $form->get('plainPassword')->getData()
        )
    );

    $entityManager->persist($user);
    $entityManager->flush();
    // do anything else you need here, like send an email

    return $userAuthenticator->authenticateUser(
        $user,
        $authenticator,
        $request
    );
}

return $this->render('registration/register.html.twig', [
    'registrationForm' => $form->createView(),
]);
```

}

Sorry the code is not properly formated I copy past it and it came that way.

Comment: But if I understand you right, there is no problem by the way this is in my database ? It will be regognized correctly by my code ? If the answer is yes, then it solved my problem :)

Comment: Yes, here you will just have the username that already exists written in the input and this input will be unmutable so when the form will be submitted, the username won't be changed. That makes it a constant and I think this is what you want to do.